# Keras tuner.search search error is giving me an error related to shapes `Shapes (None, 11, 11) and (None, 1000, 11) are incompatible`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiclass-classification, keras-tuner

I am developing an LSTM model for multi-label text classification with 11 categories.
The `keras.tuner` gives me an error while the model without tunning runs well.

I would really appreciate if someone can point out the issue behind these errors. I tried changing the `loss` to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` but it would give me other errors.

Here is my setup.
`tensorflow version:2.5.0, keras version:2.4.3`

#### Text cleaning

```
import re
df = data
REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):
    """
        text: a string
        
        return: modified initial string
    """
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text. substitute the matched string in REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE with space.
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # remove symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text. substitute the matched string in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE with nothing. 
    text = text.replace('x', '')
#    text = re.sub(r'\W+', '', text)
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # remove stopwors from text
    return text
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(clean_text)
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

#### embedding

```
MAX_NB_WORDS = 70000
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 1000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 200
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['text'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print('Shape of data tensor:', X.shape)
```

`Shape of data tensor: (10695, 1000)`

```
Y = pd.get_dummies(df['condition_predict']).values
print('Shape of label tensor:', Y.shape)
```

`Shape of label tensor: (10695, 11)`

#### training and testing data

```
def get_training_testing_data(dataframe):
    X_train_df, X_test_df, Y_train_df, Y_test_df = train_test_split(dataframe['text'],Y, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 42)
    print(X_train_df.shape,Y_train_df.shape)
    print(X_test_df.shape,Y_test_df.shape)
    return X_train_df, X_test_df, Y_train_df, Y_test_df
```

`(9625,) (9625, 11)`
`(1070,) (1070, 11)`

#### tokenizing

```
X_train_df_t = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train_df.values)
X_train_df_t = pad_sequences(X_train_df_t, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
```

#### building tuning model

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(hp.Choice('rate',
                      values=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3])))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

### setting up a random search for tuner

tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5,
    executions_per_trial=3,
    directory='hypertuning/',
    project_name='MultiClass_classification')
## searching the parameter space
epochs = 200
batch_size = 64
tuner.search(X_train_df_t, Y_train_df, 
             epochs=epochs, 
             validation_split=0.5)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\base_tuner.py in search(self, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    129 
    130             self.on_trial_begin(trial)
--> 131             self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    132             self.on_trial_end(trial)
    133         self.on_search_end()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\multi_execution_tuner.py in run_trial(self, trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
     94             copied_fit_kwargs['callbacks'] = callbacks
     95 
---> 96             history = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, fit_args, copied_fit_kwargs)
     97             for metric, epoch_values in history.history.items():
     98                 if self.oracle.objective.direction == 'min':

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\tuner.py in _build_and_fit_model(self, trial, fit_args, fit_kwargs)
    139         """
    140         model = self.hypermodel.build(trial.hyperparameters)
--> 141         return model.fit(*fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    142 
    143     def run_trial(self, trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs):

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 764             *args, **kwds))
    765 
    766     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:797 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:155 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:259 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1644 categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4862 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\falco\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 11, 11) and (None, 1000, 11) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have figured out the issue.
Somehow I completely missed/over-wrote my `LSTM` layer in the model builder.
After following changes, the random search works smoothly.

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
    #model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(hp.Choice('rate',
                      values=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3])))
    model.add(LSTM(hp.Choice('units',
                      values=[100, 300, 500]), dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```